Does ANU QRNG generated binary stream have expected characteristics?
If a QRNG perfectly adheres to Bernoulli trial with $p=0.5$ characteristics, then expected probability of $n$ consecutive $0$s or $n$ consecutive $1$s is $(0.5)^n$. However, actual frequencies of such occurences for rather lengthy binary strings obtained from ANU QRNG deviate significantly from what is expected. Why?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am looking into streams obtained by using https://qrng.anu.edu.au/random-binary/ , length of binary strings around 10000, but differences between observed and expected frequencies are still significant, I think. For example: length of binary string: 8190
Frequency of 1 consecutive ones as percentage: 48.4%
Frequency of 2 consecutive ones as percentage: 15.98%
Frequency of 3 consecutive ones as percentage: 6.84%
Frequency of 4 consecutive ones as percentage: 3.04%
Frequency of 5 consecutive ones as percentage: 1.51%

Clarifications such as your comment, belong directly in the posted question.  Beyond that, is it possible for you to obtain the exact (mathematical) algorithm used to generate the random binary strings?  True randomness is tough to generate.  A software algorithm might well be based on (for example) the CPU time in milli-seconds, or something similar.  Based on your posted question, one might suspect bias in the algorithm.  However, without being provided the exact specification of the algorithm, I don't see how the issue of bias can be investigated.

ANU is Australian National University, but what is QRNG?

QRNG is obviously Quantum Random Numbers Generator, and it gives much better observed frequencies than the ones I originally reported, much closer to theoretical expected frequencies. The problem was that I did not check the code provided by chatGPT, that I used overconfidently for analysis of these random binary strings. After its correction, there is no need for further clarification.
